# how to get the most recent variable added to a list in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a list in python named "worldPos" and it constantly adds the position of the mouse cursor to the list as x and y coordinates. How can I get the most recent x and y coordinates added to the list?

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')

cnv = Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 800)
cnv.pack()
worldPos = []

def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y

    worldPos.append((x,y))

root.bind('<Motion>', motion)

mainloop()
```

Comment: `lastx, lasty = worldPos[-1]`

Comment: just by coincidence. He may decide to add the elements in front. So it would be `worldPos[0]`

Answer (score 2):

The `.append()` method adds to the very end of the list.

This location can be addressed by `list_name[-1]`. Where the minus sign indicates indexing from the back of the list.

However you are adding two items as a tuple, so you'll want to pull:

```
x,y = worldPos[-1]
```

If you instead added the items to the front of the list

```
worldPos[0:0] = (x,y)
```

You would then index from the front of the list

```
x,y = worldPos[0]
```

Enjoy and good luck!

p.s. Be sure to accept this as an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: cheeky... 4.5 mins late :)

Comment: Yeah. At least I added some explanation and context. I'll admit though, low hanging fruit.

Comment: upvoted! that's life :)

Comment: then, if you want to make a difference, you could add the solution in case he wanted to add the events in front of the list